# Clear shipping_*fields in WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to always have the "Ship to a different adress" cleared when a user is buying in WooCommerce Checkout. The following code is though doing aboslutely nothing. Does it have todo with cookies?

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'remove_clear_checkout_shipping_fields', 10, 2 );
function remove_clear_checkout_shipping_fields( $value, $input ) {
    if ( strpos( $input, 'shipping_' ) !== FALSE ) {
        $value = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can modify each field:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

  $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_state'] = '';

  return $fields;
}
```

Just remove unnecessary fields.

Comment: Please improve formatting of the code and give some description as well.

Comment: @Alex Nick That code removes the shipping fields. That's not quite what I want. I want to CLEAR the values that has been entered in a earlier order.